# How exactly does a Max 2 Sat reduce to a 3 Sat?

Tags: algorithm, np, 2-satisfiability

I've been reading [this](http://web.stanford.edu/~rrwill/williams-max2sat-encyc.pdf) article which tries and explains how the max 2 sat problem is essentially a 3-sat problem and is NP-hard. 
However, if you see the article, I'm *not able to understand why*, after `ci` is satisfied, 7 out of 10 clauses are satisfied and if it is not satisfied, the 6 out of 10 clauses are satisfied.

Can someone explain to me in simple terms, and demystify what exactly the article wants to convey? Essentially, I have come to know that a max-2-sat problem is the same as a 3 sat problem. The question is I'm not able to understand why.

More formally, I wish to solve this problem:

> Consider the problem MAX2SAT described as follows.
>   Given a 2-CNF (Conjunctive Normal Form) Boolean expression  (with m
>   clauses, n variables) and an integer k, Decide if there is an
>   assignment satisfying at least ‘k’ of the total clauses? Compute the
>   complexity class (P or NP or NP Complete) of the MAX2SAT with
>   justification.

Comment: This is probably better suited for Computer Science instead of Stackoverflow

Comment: well this is doing the reverse of what your asking. Does it make sense the other way?

Answer (score 1):

Well, a key misunderstanding that we should talk about first is that this is not reducing Max-2-sat to 3-sat as your title says. In order to prove something (in this case Max-2-sat) is np-hard, we must to the opposite and reduce 3-sat (or any other known np-hard problem) to it.

If we do this, then we show that IF the thing that we reduced to (max-2-sat) isn't np-hard THEN 3-sat isn't either because we could just do our reduction and solve 3-sat efficiently via max-2-sat. We know this to be impossible (3-sat is known np-complete, someone else did the hard work) so the idea that max-2-sat isn't np-hard is a contradiction.

Reducing TO 3-sat doesn't tell us much. Max-2-sat could still be easy in that case. In that case, Maybe reducing to 3-sat was just a bad idea and it's easier to just tackle it directly. It is only doing the reverse that proves what you are trying to show